# Adjoin complex numbers to an arbitrary field?

Tags: complex-numbers, finite-fields

This is probably nonsense but I'm throwing it out there. I don't think I can even explain the question very well: Has anyone seen bizarre things such as adjoining, say $i$ or $\pi$, to say a finite field? Would anything such as $zm$, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m \in \mathbb{F}_q$ be made to have any useful meaning? In the past the invention of things such as $\sqrt{-1}$, though intuitive enough for us these days, must have been rather abstract and "nonsensical" for folks those days. Yet complex numbers are curiously useful to solve problems about things which should have nothing to do with these.

Comment: You can adjoin a square root of $-1$ to any field. In fact many fields (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$) already contain one.

Comment: $\pi$ probably wouldn't have any useful meaning, but it can have a meaning if you adjoin an algebraic number instead.

Comment: Yes but I mean the $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{C}$, that is, an element of another completely different field

Comment: @user152169 Yes, but you can instead think of $i$ as just a root of $x^2+1$, which can make sense in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: Say you have some pairs $zm, zt$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m,t \in \mathbb{F}_q$. Perhaps we could an addition such as $zm + zt = z(m + t)$ with $m + t$ regular addition in the finite field, or so.

Comment: $i$ was just an example. I mean complex numbers, including reals, making "pairs" with elements in a finite field

Comment: The $i$ that you add will not have all the features of the familiar $i$. For example, if the field we are working in has characteristic $p$, we will have   $i+i+\cdots+i$ ($p$ times) is equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes! Now I wonder if there are some binary operations that we can define on such pairs and perhaps some distance and topology?

Comment: Look, you can probably add your big toe to a finite field, but that doesn't mean you'll be able to put your sock on over it.

Comment: You can use pairs in the sense that you get a ring $\Bbb{F}_q\times\Bbb{C}$. But 1) that is not a field, 2) the $-1$ that you get as $i^2$ will then be a different element from the $-1$ of the field $\Bbb{F}_q$. You can define a metric, or a topology, on that direct product, but ... why?

Comment: I think user352567 got it non? There is a field, $\mathbb{C}_p$, containing the usual complex numbers and the Teichmuller representatives of finite fields with characteristic $p$ (when reduced mod p these give the finite field elements). Thus for instance $\mathbb{\pi} m \in \mathbb{C}_p$, with $m$ a root of $x^p-x$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $m \pmod{p} \in \mathbb{F}_p$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to make sense of what you're asking.

If you want to a adjoin a single *algebraic* number to $\mathbb{Q}$, then you pick a root of some (monic) polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. You could equally well take that polynomial to have integral coefficients by clearing denominators (as this doesn't change the roots), and then take its reduction modulo a prime $p$, and adjoin a root of the resulting element of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ to get an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

One issue with this is that, when you cleared denominators, the resulting integral coefficients could have been partially/entirely divisible by $p$, so the resulting extension of finite fields could bear little resemblance to the extension of the rationals. One can get around this by restricting to algebraic *integers*, as opposed to algebraic *numbers*. This simply means that you start with a monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$, and then any root of that can be used to make an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, or any field for that matter. This perspective is fundamental in algebraic number theory.

If you want to adjoin a single *transcendental* number to $\mathbb{Q}$, then as a field extension that's just isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, so perhaps the most reasonable analog over the finite field would just be $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$. Basically, the point is that from the perspective of *solely* field theory, $\pi$ is not much different than any other transcendental.

A rather different way one might address your question is by discussing the field called $\mathbb{C}_p$, which is the completion of the algebraic closure of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Coupled with what are called Teichmuller representatives, and an application of the axiom of choice, one actually can "make sense" of something like $zm$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $m\in \mathbb{F}_p$, but I should acknowledge that that is not a useful way to think about things (as far as I know).